# SQL query to calculate table based on previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to transform a table from tab A to Table B :
I used windowing function like Lag but it couldn't help
table 1 :

| Concat_date_hour | Type | Value | Next_Movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021092414 | D | 16923 | 63 |
| 2021092415 | D | 0 | 149 |
| 2021092415 | D | 0 | -56 |
| 2021092415 | D | 0 | -131 |
| 2021092415 | D | 0 | -79 |

Output table :

| Concat_date_hour | Type | Actual Value | New value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021092414 | D | 16923 | 16986 |
| 2021092415 | D | 16986 | 17135 |
| 2021092415 | D | 17135 | 17079 |
| 2021092415 | D | 17079 | 16948 |
| 2021092415 | D | 16948 | 16869 |

PS type can be different from D

Comment: How do you know which value to chose when there are several rows with the same Concat_date_hour?

Comment: Have a search for "cumulative `SUM`"

Comment: Rows in a table are, by definition, unordered. Without columns to support your desired order, your goal might be impossible.  And if Type might contain different values, add some sample rows to illustrate that.

Comment: Without using LEAD & Lag :  

select Concat_date_hour,DType, case when rn=1 then [Value] else cast(balance as bigint)-cast(Next_Movement as bigint) end as ActualValue,balance as Next_Movement 
   from(
   select Concat_date_hour,DType, [Value], Next_Movement, sum(isnull([Value], 0)+isnull(Next_Movement, 0))  over (order by rn) balance,rn   from (
   select Concat_date_hour,DType, [Value], Next_Movement, row_number() over (order by Concat_date_hour) rn  from #temp ) tab ) Tab2

Comment: Looks like LEAD/LAG refered to as an existing answer is not relevant. Output table  shows OP wants running total.

Comment: Agreed, dupe is wrong @MitchWheat please reopen

Comment: Looks like you need to add the previous non-null `Value` to a running sum of `Next_Movement`

Answer (score 1):

As an ordering column is missing in the source table it will be created on the fly. Other parts of the query depend on that `rn` arbitrary ordering column.

```
select Concat_date_hour, Type,
  --rn, Value, Next_Movement, 
  rt - Next_Movement actual, rt [new value]
from (
  select *, sum(Value + Next_Movement) over (partition by Type order by Concat_date_hour, rn) rt
  from (
     select  *, row_number() over(partition by Type, Concat_date_hour order by Concat_date_hour) rn
     from tbl ) t
) t
order by Type, Concat_date_hour, rn;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af9ea79784ffca9a7d94994b61ac3feb) Note the extra row added to the original sample data.